# Unable to automatically step into the server. The remote procedure could not be debugged

Tags: wcf, debugging, iis, remote-debugging

I am having a problem stepping into code which is a website hosted on IIS7.

Basically I have a test class which calls a WCF service like so

```
ISecurityService service = new SecurityServiceClient();
MembershipUser membershipUser = null;
membershipUser = service.GetMembershipUser("Mark"); // THIS LINE FAILS!!!
```

I get the following error but I have everything enabled as far as I know, i.e.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Here is the error msg, I would appreciated any feedback.  If I don't try and step into the line above then all works ok.

> ---
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Unable to automatically step into the server. The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled on the server. See help for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using vista by any chance?

anyways, take a look at this post:
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/12/28/Fix-problems-with-Visual-Studio-F5-debugging-of-ASP.NET-applications-on-IIS7-Vista.aspx

hope it helps

EDIT: have a look here as well
[Return MembershipUser using WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939897/return-membershipuser-using-wcf-service)

Comment: Actually i am using Windows 7, if i do an F5 it works fine... its when i try and step into my wcf server (hosted in IIS) from my class libraru where my tests are

Answer (score 1):

dont forget to set compilation debug="true" in your wcf service web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error. The problem was that the WCF web service's site on IIS was stopped, because another process was occupying the same port!

To discover what process is, from the command prompt:

```
netstat -aon | find ":your_iis_web_services_port_number"
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try turning on anonymous authentication in IIS. That worked for me when I encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`dont forget to set compilation debug="true" in your wcf service web.config file.`

If your startup project different from the WCF Service that is in question and you have `start wcf service host when debugging another project in the same solution` checked, you will need to set `compilation debug="true"` in that projects App.config.