# Return MembershipUser from WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have implemented a SQL Membership provider for my WCF service. The service gets accessed through the internet by a WPF client. I have a service getUser() which should return the a user. 
Is it ok to return a MembershipUser by that method because I have read in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939897/return-membershipuser-using-wcf-service) that it is not possible to do that because the class has a SecurityAttribute and XmlSerializer cannot serialize it.

Edit:
Also is it safe to return this type to the client. Is there any potential for misuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure the specific answer on whether that type can be serialized or not ... but just give it a try. If you get an error, then simply make a proxy type that includes all the information you need to return. And return that in your WCF method :-)

Comment: I could do that but my service and client already are big in size so there will be a lot of changing to the code.

Comment: how could that possibly be? if you're developing the membership provider now, how could the dependency have grown so large as to be onerous to change? Generally speaking, you should strive to limit cross-cutting concerns that would require you to change a bunch of code if modified

Comment: i used the default membership provider and worked with that. I've been working for a month this way, but since this is my first WCF, WPF project I didn't have any plan upfront because I didn't know the possibilities of the frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember if that worked for us, but in the worst case you can create a DTO object (lets say MyMembershipUser) and create mapping from MembershipUser to MyMembershipUser.
That's should be pretty straight forward.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Maps MembershipUser entity to MyMembershipUser business object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">A MembershipUser entity.</param>
    /// <returns>A product business object.</returns>
    internal static MyMembershipUser Map(MembershipUser entity)
    {
        return new MyMembershipUser 
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Name= entity.Name,
        };
    }
```