# WCF timeout against Azure WebRole when serializing certain types of collections

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, azure, timeout

I have a stateless backend service hosted on an **Azure Web Role** which queries an **Entity Framework** container, among other things. Clients communicate with it using **WCF** and `wsHttpBinding`. **The clients receive a timeout from backend when calling certain methods**, and even though I worked around this in some cases, I can't seem to pinpoint the underlying cause.

Here's what I know so far:

- The failing methods seem to be the ones that return certain types of collections. This includes `IEnumerable<T>` with results obtained from LINQ queries, and `MembershipUserCollection`.
- In some cases the workaround was to add `.ToList()` to the collection being returned.
- Those methods fail **only** when the backend is hosted in Azure.
- The Azure load balancer doesn't seem to be the cause but the symptom: every time a method times out, the log reveals that it had actually exited long before the 1 minute limit.

And here's one of the methods that fail:

**WCF interface**:

```
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IBackendService/GetAllUsers", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IBackendService/GetAllUsersResponse")]
    MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
```

**WCF Implementation** (simplified):

```
    protected UserRepository Users;

    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        // Get all users in the page range specified.
        var userEntities = Users.GetAll();
        var users = new MembershipUserCollection();
        userEntities = userEntities.GetPagedRange(pageIndex, pageSize).ToList();
        userEntities.ForEach(ue => users.Add(Mappings.Map<UserEntity, User>(ue)));
        totalRecords = userEntities.Count();
        return users;
    }
```

**Mappings** is a class that defines mapping rules between data and business objects using AutoMapper. `User` inherits from `MembershipUser`. Here's what's relevant from it: (WIP. Please excuse the mess.)

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserEntity, User>()
            .ConstructUsing(ue => new User
                (
                ue.UserId,
                ue.ProviderName,
                ue.UserName,
                ue.Email,
                ue.PasswordQuestion,
                ue.IsApproved,
                ue.IsLockedOut,
                ue.CreationDate,
                ue.LastLoginDate.HasValue ? ue.LastLoginDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                ue.LastActivityDate.HasValue ? ue.LastActivityDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                ue.LastPasswordChangedDate.HasValue ? ue.LastPasswordChangedDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                ue.LastLockoutDate.HasValue ? ue.LastLockoutDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                ue.Comment,
                ue.Customers.Select(Map<CustomerEntity, Customer>).ToList(),
                ue.Roles.Select(Map<RoleEntity, Role>).ToList(),
                ue.Roles.SelectMany(r => r.Activities).Select(Map<ActivityEntity, Activity>).ToList()
                ))
            .IgnoreAllNonExisting();

        Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserEntity>()
            .ForMember(ue => ue.Comment, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.Comment))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.CreationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.CreationDate))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.Email))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.IsApproved, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.IsApproved))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.IsLockedOut, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.IsLockedOut))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.LastActivityDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.LastActivityDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : u.LastActivityDate))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.LastLockoutDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.LastLockoutDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : u.LastLockoutDate))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.LastLoginDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.LastLoginDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : u.LastLoginDate))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.LastPasswordChangedDate,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.LastPasswordChangedDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) ? (DateTime?)null : u.LastPasswordChangedDate))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.PasswordQuestion, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.PasswordQuestion))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.ProviderName, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.ProviderName))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => (int)u.ProviderUserKey))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.UserName))
            .ForMember(ue => ue.Password, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(ue => ue.PasswordAnswer, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(ue => ue.ApplicationName, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(ue => ue.Roles, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(ue => ue.Customers, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

**IgnoreAllNonExisting** is an extension method:

```
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
        var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType == sourceType && x.DestinationType == destinationType);
        foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }

        return expression;
    }
```

My best guess is that this is a serialization problem in the WCF layer, but I don't know what might be triggering it. Other than that,
I'm completely clueless.

What else should I check? Do you need any more info?

**EDIT: Added moar snippets for clarification.**

Comment: Where does Mappings.Map come from? Sometimes there can be EF serialization issues with Lazy Loading of navigable properties causing  recursive serialization

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a helper class that creates AutoMapper rules to map data objects to business objects and vice versa. I'll add a snippet for clarification, forgot about that one.

Comment: Aha. I use ValueInjector. They are both gr8. Are the collections that fail collections like User where a User has a Roles Collection and each Role might have a Users Collection. Automapper might be clever enough to not serialize forever but you might be timing out returning every user in your system?

Comment: Just added the snippets with the (messy) mapping rules. I hadn't thought about that circular dependency you mention, you might be onto something there. However, what puzzles me is that this same code works when hosted **outside** Azure.

Comment: I just checked, and the ``Users`` navigation property in ``RoleEntity`` is being ignored, so I guess there won't be an infinite loop there.

Comment: The circular dependency problem is the only issue I could think of. Sorry I can't help more. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I finally found the answer.

It seems that the `MembershipUser` class **is not serializable at all**, even though it's marked with the `Serializable` attribute. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939897/return-membershipuser-using-wcf-service), it's also marked with `SecurityPermission` attributes, which forbid serialization for security reasons.

What sense does it make to mark a class with contradicting attributes, I guess I'll never 
know.

What's even stranger is that the timeout issue only occurs when hosting the WCF service on an Azure WebRole. If you host it elsewhere, it throws a `CommunicationException`, which makes sense. I guess there's got to be some kind of bug in Azure over there.

Anyway, **I solved this by making my** `User` **class NOT inherit from** `MembershipUser`, and **replaced occurrences of** `MembershipUserCollection` **with** `IEnumerable<User>`.

Hope this helps somebody else.